# Create a new version on ReadTheDocs

Tags: read-the-docs

I need help in setting up a new version for our documentation on ReadTheDocs. Currently, we have the documentation for versions 6 and 7 of our product published on our ReadTheDocs site, and this documentation comes from a private repository on GitHub. We're now rolling out version 8 of the product and need to set up a new version for v8 documentation on ReadTheDocs. Could somebody let me know how I can proceed with it?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create an '8' branch in the documentation repository on GitHub. Then you’ll have the option to activate it on ReadTheDocs.